# Weird behavior of Value unpacking when splitting string in Python

Tags: python, string, split, list-comprehension

Use case: I've got a long string that is divided by linebreaks, and each line has two element separated by a comma.

Ideally, this should work

```
[(x, y) for line in lines.split() for x, y in line.split(',')]
```

But it doesn't, and yields a ValueError the same as below. So I tried to decompose the problem to figure out what's going on here

```
lines = \
"""a,b
c,d
e,f
g,h"""

lines = [line for line in lines.split()]

print(lines)
print(len(lines))
print([len(line) for line in lines])
print(all(',' in line for line in lines))

[(x, y) for l in lines for x,y in l.split(',')]
```

Yields:

```
/usr/bin/python3m /home/alex/PycharmProjects/test.py
['a,b', 'c,d', 'e,f', 'g,h']
4
[3, 3, 3, 3]
True

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/alex/PycharmProjects/test.py", line 74, in <module>
...
File "/home/alex/PycharmProjects/test.py", line 63, in <listcomp>
[(x, y) for l in sines for x,y in l.split(',')]
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Yet if I replace the list comprehension in the last line with a classic for loop:

```
for line in lines:
x, y = line.split(',')
```

It executes successfully:

```
['a,b', 'c,d', 'e,f', 'g,h']
4
True
[3, 3, 3, 3]
a b
c d
e f
g h
```

This is driving me absolutely insane. If I further decompose it, I find that list, set, and generator comprehensions shit themselves trying to do this:

```
[(x,y) for x, y in "a,b".split(",")]
```

Anyone have an idea about why this occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
for x, y in "a,b".split(",")
```

is looking for *two-item* iterables that are *inside* the iterable (list) returned by `"a,b".split(",")`.

However, all it finds is `'a'` and `'b'`:

```
>>> "a,b".split(",")
['a', 'b']
>>>
```

Since both of these are only *one-item* iterables (strings with one character), the code breaks.

---

Considering the above, watch what happens when an extra character is added to each side of the comma:

```
>>> "ax,by".split(",")
['ax', 'by']
>>> [(x,y) for x, y in "ax,by".split(",")]
[('a', 'x'), ('b', 'y')]
>>>
```

As you can see, the code now works.

This is because `"ax,by".split(",")` returns an iterable (list) that contains two-item iterables (strings with two characters).  Furthermore, this is exactly what `for x, y in` is looking for.

---

However, you could also place the last part in a tuple:

```
>>> ("a,b".split(","),)
(['a', 'b'],)
>>> [(x,y) for x, y in ("a,b".split(","),)]
[('a', 'b')]
>>>
```

`("a,b".split(","),)` returns an iterable (tuple) that contains two-item iterables (a list with two strings).  Once again, this is exactly what `for x, y in` is looking for, so the code works.

---

With all this in mind, the below should fix your problem:

```
[(x, y) for line in lines.split() for x, y in (line.split(','),)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on why my assumptions were wrong. Appreciated it :)

Answer (score 1):

why not this?

```
[tuple(l.split(',')) for l in lines ]
```

`l.split(',')` produces only two items for each `l`, not an iterable of two items per each `l`

Comment: Sure, I could do that, but it defeats the point of tuple unpacking especially if I wanted to do an operation on certain elements without having to break out the brackets and indices :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
lines = """
a,b
c,d
e,f
g,h
"""

lines = [line for line in lines.split()]

print(lines)
print(len(lines))
print([len(line) for line in lines])
print(all(',' in line for line in lines))

[l.split(",") for l in lines]
```